# What mysql java driver version are you supposed to use with the latest mysql server

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jdbc

What mysql java driver version are you supposed to use with the latest mysql [5.5.7.RC](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.5.html#downloads) server. (Env: Hibernate 3.3.x)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recommended versions can be found [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-j-versions.html). It recommends using MySQL Connector/J 5.1 and higher.

The latest release is [MySQL Connector/J 5.1.13](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) (release 24 June 2010). MySQL Connector/J 5.1.14 isn't released yet.